# Why systemd fails to kill user process? "Failed to kill control group" "ignoring: Operation not permitted"

Tags: systemd, systemd-user

I start `qemu` as a user scope task `sytemd-run --user qemu-system... -pidfile pidfile`

on shutdown, systemd claims it failed to kill it (without ever trying) and sends a `SIGKILL`, which doesn't terminate qemu properly and keep the pidfile laying around.

```
$ journalctl --user -b -1
...
systemd[884]: run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope, ignoring: Operation not permitted
systemd[884]: run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope: Killing process 23775 (qemu-system-x86) with signal SIGKILL.
systemd[884]: run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope: Killing process 23778 (kvm-nx-lpage-recovery-23775) with signal SIGKILL.
systemd[884]: run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope: Failed to kill control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope, ignoring: Operation not permitted
systemd[884]: Stopped /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -pidfile pidfile ...
systemd[884]: run-r0d56e38ca97d4493a5f496a19d18f6ae.scope: Consumed 30.007s CPU time, 774.1M memory peak, 0B memory swap peak.
```

I tried searching for the strings on the failure: `"Failed to kill control group" "ignoring: Operation not permitted"` and got zero results anywhere.

the process is easily killable by the user or root. A simple `SIGTERM` ends the process in 1ms. So it is not timing out either. All the log lines above happens in the same second btw.

What is causing that "Operation not permitted"?